# WP: Adding a div to WooCommerce single products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm attempting to add a div section to a every single product on WooComerce. I've created a child theme of the Storefront theme. From here I'm completely lost however, WooCommerce seems a little counter intuitive.

I'm attempting to add the new div section under the product description section. It can't be a particularity task, I've been stuck on this for hours though fumbling through the template files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation on how to override core WooCommerce template :

https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

If you take a look at the files for the 2.4.7 version of WooCommerce :

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/tree/2.4.7/templates

There is a file description in tabs directory: [single-product/tabs/description.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.4.7/templates/single-product/tabs/description.php)

Take a look at all file under `single-product` folder and you will understand how the single product page is built.